# ArgumentError: invalid date in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello i finding average of array of dates. while running the code i am getting error as--> **ArgumentError: invalid date in ROR**

**This is how my code looks like ---->**

```
 arrays = [Tue, 08 Dec 2020 20:21:03 IST +05:30, Tue, 08 Dec 2020 20:21:05 IST +05:30]  # this is the date format i am getting from the database
 i = 0
  arrays.each do |array|   # arrays get value as array of dates 
    array1[i] = Date.parse(array.strftime('%Y-%d-%m')) # i am getting the error in this line 
    i = i+1
  end
```

Comment: Please show the dates from `arrays`.

Comment: check if your code is generating 31 April or 29th Feb 30th Feb

Comment: arrays = [Tue, 08 Dec 2020 20:21:03 IST +05:30, Tue, 08 Dec 2020 20:21:05 IST +05:30]  # this is the date format i am getting from the database @stolarz

Comment: its not genarating  31st apr or 29 feb or 30 feb @DeepakMahakale

Comment: Maybe try adding a rescue block and catch the error try logging the date this is failing for

Comment: It seems you already have a DateTime object why do you need to parse it again?

Comment: Maybe try adding what you want to achieve so that people can help accordingly

Comment: `Date.parse` might not be needed here, but we don't know what you want to achieve with this code.

Answer (score 0):

There 2 possibilities.

- You got `DateTime` object on your array

```
arrays.map!{|date| date.strftime('%Y-%d-%m')}
```

- You got `String` object (need to parse it before)

```
arrays.map!{|str| Date.parse(str).strftime('%Y-%d-%m')}
```

To check what's the class of elements on you array you can do:

```
arrays.first.class
```